# Parse SMS PDU on go

Tags: go, sms, pdu, smspdu

Is it possible to parse SMS PDU using just golang

executing AT command

```
AT+CMGF=0
OK

AT+CMGL=4
+CMGL: 0,1,,26
0791361907002039040C9136198748701300005150713220052308C8303A8C0EA3C3
```

is there way to decode this in go?

```
0791361907002039040C9136198748701300005150713220052308C8303A8C0EA3C3
```

if there's not, can you suggest a work around.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: Could you provide your current implementation or some other go specific detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. A quick [search](http://go-search.org/search?q=pdu) turned up: [github.com/xlab/at/sms](https://godoc.org/github.com/xlab/at/sms). Here's an example program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/xlab/at/sms"
)

func main() {
    bs, err := hex.DecodeString("0791361907002039040C9136198748701300005150713220052308C8303A8C0EA3C3")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    msg := new(sms.Message)
    msg.ReadFrom(bs)
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

Running that gives me:

```
&{0 0 0 0 {63567471770 0 0x57bac0} +639170000293 +639178840731 Hahahaha 0 false false false false false false false}
```

Also the parent package seems like it has a bunch of functions you may find useful.